# Parallel Processing of Membership Searches With Large Datasets

Tags: python, parallel-processing, bioinformatics

I am performing a membership search where each member of a small list (list of strings of nucleotide reads) is tested for membership in a very large trie of associated k-mers.

Each nucleotide read is searched about 200 times (amount of k-mers per read), and this script must be able to handle files containing ones to tens of billions of reads. I have designed the script so as to process one read at a time, using the two (paired end) input fastq files as generators.

The script works fine, but as it stands now, may take a few days to a few weeks to complete.

```
def readTrim1(inRead, indexList):

    # k-merize inRead.
    # for each k-mer in inRead
        #check if k-mer is present in trie of k-mres.
    # reassemble k-mers into read and return validated read.

for read1, read2 in readLists:
    finalRead1 = readTrim1(read1, indexList)  # send to method that will perform 
                                              # membership search.

    finalRead2 = readTrim2(read1, indexList)  # Same but for second read.
```

Essentially, one read at a time is sent to a method that will perform the roughly 200 membership searches. This will happen once for each read, and once complete, the next read will be processed.

How can I make use of multiple processesors (as many as a given machine can provide) to make this computation more efficient, while still maintaining the specific order of reads?

I believe the parallelization should take place in main, as I believe the limiting factor is the large amount of reads to be processed, and not so much the membership searching method itself.

I have looked at the following sites for research, but have not found an example quite like mine:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing 
http://www.parallelpython.com/

Thank You

Comment: Start by reading a chuck of reads into memory. Then, spawn _n_ consumers to perform your membership search. Rinse and repeat until all data is read from your files. I think this would be best done using Java.

Comment: Take a look at the `multiprocessing`, module for a start (http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Isn't this a short-read alignment problem? If you combined all the kmers, considered it to be a pseudo-genome sequence and ran a no-mismatch alignment against it - it would take a few seconds using modern tools. When I had to do this, I used [bowtie](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/index.shtml)

Comment: @Spade hmm that's a great idea! The biggest difference between your approach and my script is that I allow for read trimming as well as filtration. To my knowledge this is not possible with Bowtie without some scripting involved. I think, however, comparing these two methods would be a great way to test the efficacy of this script.

Comment: @Malonge That is the approach I used to write the tails algorithm used in [this work](http://www.plantcell.org/content/25/7/2417.full.pdf+html) .I had to allow for read trimming too and remember doing it from a script that then invoked bowtie in multiprocessing mode. Don't have the details or the script - was over 5 years ago.